# Eclipse couldn't startup tomcat server after configuring SSL at server.xml of tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ssl, https, tomcat7

As I want to change tomcat from http to https, so I change server.xml like this:

```
<!--
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" /> 
-->
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https"
               secure="true" clientAuth="false" connectionTimeout="20000" 
               keystoreFile="D:/sslDemo/tomcat.keystore" 
               keystorePass="123456" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Before change, I could startup tomcat at Eclipse, but failed after changing.
The error tips like this:

```
Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

I could start it up by cmd.
Could anyone kindly advise what is the problem? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just increase server startup timeout[image]

goto server view, double click on one of the server, expand time out option and set value to it